# Restrict access to subdirectory in Apache

Tags: apache-httpd, webserver, htaccess, authorization

I've a very easy question. However I have been digging all the manuals for an answer for a full day already.

What I want is to configure Apache to give anyone read access to /var/www but restrict /var/www/private to my team only. I'm looking for the new solution of version 2.4. Thus not using deprecated directives like `Allow`, `Deny`, `Order` and `Satisfy`. I have write permission for the /etc/apache2/sites-available/* files but only read permission for /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.

What I've tried so far is this:
Content of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
<Directory />
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Content of /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:

```
<Directory /var/www/private>
    Require group team
</Directory>
```

But with this configuration everyone has access to /var/www/private. And this I can understand, since Apache merges all the environments for /var/www/private to something like this:

```
Require all denied  # inherited from /
Require all granted # inherited from /var/www
Require group team  # inherited from /var/www/private
```

And since `Require` directives outside `<RequireAll>`, `<RequireAny>` or `<RequireNone>` are equivalent to being in a `<RequireAny>` block, the merged view is thus:

```
<RequireAny>
    Require all denied  # inherited from /
    Require all granted # inherited from /var/www
    Require group team  # inherited from /var/www/private
</RequireAny>
```

And this shows clearly why /var/www/private is open for everyone (the second statement always matches).

My question is thus: "Can you somehow overide the `Require all granted` in a parent directory in a subdirectory or can you change the default `<RequireAny>` behaviour to `<RequireAll>`?"

Comment: There's no reason `require group team` won't do what you want except you need to create the group in a htpasswd file (system group doesn't apply) and the users need to login with their user/pass.

Comment: Require directives default to `RequireAny` so it can usually be omitted unless you need to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default Apache settings for `/var/www` meet your requirements already.  You can restrict access to `/var/www/private` using `Require group team` as you suggested, by adding the missing configuration as follows.

Require directives default to RequireAny so it can usually be omitted unless you need to change it as shown in the configuration below.

Create a `.groups` file like this in a suitable location for your system:

```
# group: memberOne memberTwo memberThree etc
team: richard david jane bill
```

Then generate a `.password` file of users and hashed passwords:

```
$ htpasswd -c /path/to/file/.passwords richard
```

Run the same command for each group member who needs access, but omit the `-c` (create) flag or you'll overwrite the password file with a new blank one.

Configure your Apache directives as follows, setting the correct path to the `.passwords` and `.groups` files you created above.

```
<Location /private>
Options Indexes
  AuthType basic
  AuthName "login info required"
  AuthUserFile path/to/file/.passwords
  AuthGroupFile path/to/file/.groups
<RequireAll>
  Require all granted
  Require group team
</RequireAll>
</Location>
```

Restart Apache and you're done.

Comment: I know how to create groups. I just left them out for brevity.
The problem with leaving out the <Directory /var/www> section is that I don't have write access to apache2.conf. I'm on a shared hosting where I can only modify the VirtualHost file.

Comment: I don't see the problem with `/var/www`. The default configuration appears what you want for that directory, so you can leave it alone.  Just add the `<Directory "/var/www/private">` section to the virtual host's file above/outside of the `VirtualHost` directive and you're good to go.

Comment: The problem at my host is that apache2.conf does have the <Directory /var/www> Require all granted</Directory> in there by default. I cannot change that. Therefore my question, how to revoke access rights for subdirectories.

Comment: My example does exactly that (revokes access rights for sub-directories). The `Require group team` directive takes precedence over the `Require all granted` directive on the parent directory.

Comment: I tried your answer. I had to change filenames because they don't correspond with your commands.
With your example I can browse to http://localhost/private/index.html. I'm not asked for any password, but see the content. This is the exact behaviour in my original question. Unfortunately, your answer is thus not helpfull.

Comment: The file names are whatever you create.  I gave example names to match the directives I provided. It seems you either didn't set the correct paths, didn't correctly create the files, or didn't restart Apache. "Configure your Apache directives as follows, setting the correct path to the .passwords and .groups files you created above."  Check the output of `apachectl -t` or `httpd -t` for syntax errors.

Comment: I did change the filenames and I did restart apache. `apachectl -t` gives as output `Syntax OK`. The output of the logs shows: `"GET /private/index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 409 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"` You would expect a 401 http response instead of a 200 code.

Comment: Can you post your VirtualHost config?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68620/discussion-between-alxs-and-richard-brinkman).

Comment: The trick is to switch from <Directory /var/www/private> to <Location /private>.
Why this is the case is a mystery for me. Accoriding to  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#page-header both longer directory pathnames and location overides the shorter pathname. In practice this is only the case in the latter.

Comment: No.  Both methods work as intended per official documentation.  The problem you observed was caused by your 000-default.conf.  `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` isn't parent to `<Directory "/var/www/private">`, so you weren't actually seeing the `/var/www/private` directory you thought you were looking at in your browser.  Confusion ensued.